# What does the "c" stand for in a Google Cloud Platform internal DNS FQDN?

Tags: syntax, dns, google-compute-engine, internals, fqdn

I'm going through the [GCP internal DNS documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns), and am curious about what the `c` in the FQDN stands for. GCP provides two types of internal DNS types, and the structure of the fully qualified domain names for both types contains a `c` as per:

- `[INSTANCE_NAME].[ZONE].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal`

or:

- `[INSTANCE_NAME].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal`

I can find a reference to all the components of the FQDN but the `c`. Does anyone know what it is referring to? My best guess here is that it is a reference to a class C network.

Answer (score 0):

It is a subdomain under *[PROJECT_ID].internal* and GCP VM instance naming convention.

A fully qualified domain name (FQDN) consists of a domain name followed by instance name. As you have seen, GCP has two [types of internal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#instance-fully-qualified-domain-names) (i.e. zonal and global). For Compute Engine, these DNS entries get automatically created under subdomain ***.c***.